# How would I convert this simple coutning up by evens program to detect an odd number and count up by odds?

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, methods

```
     public static void Main()
        {
            EvenNumbers();
        }


        public  static void EvenNumbers()
        {
            int written = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            for (int i = 0; i <= written; i++)
            {
                if (i % 2 == 1)
                    continue;
                     Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Yes I'm aware I've declared the code in a different method from the main method despite with a program this simple there being no need to its just for simple practice. I'm just wondering as you can see in the code it detects the input of the user and then from that input uses a for loop and counts up to it evenly. However, I want it to count up to it by odds if I put an odd number in. How could I do this?

Comment: Was it you who wrote it?

Comment: "i % 2 == 1" is saying if the number divided by two leaves a remainder then skip it. Just change the 1 to a 0. The % is the same as the Modulus operator in math.

Comment: Odds of counting correctly is lower that correctly counting odds :)

Answer (score 0):

Check for `i % 2 != written % 2`.

Answer (score 0):

To print odd or even numbers, the line `if (i % 2 == x)` needs to have `x=1` to print even numbers and `x=0` to print odd numbers. If you take `written % 2` you will get `0` if it is even and `1` if it is odd. Since you want to print even numbers if the input number is even and odd numbers if the input is odd, you store a number in the variable `modNumber` that you will then use in place of `x` in `if (i % 2 == x)`. The line `int modNumber = written % 2 == 1 ? 0 : 1` in English means "The int modNumber equals 0 if written % 2 == 1, otherwise it equals 1".

```
    public  static void EvenNumbers()
    {
        int written = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int modNumber = written % 2 == 1 ? 0 : 1;
        for (int i = 0; i <= written; i++)
        {
            if (i % 2 == modNumber)
                continue;

            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please explain to me what modnumber does and what the 0 : 1 would be used for?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to count by twos.  That will work for either even or odd numbers.  For odd numbers, you need to start at 1, and for even numbers, you need to start at 0.  You can easily figure out which you need by doing a single `mod` operation.  `x % 2` will be 1 for odd numbers, and zero for even numbers.

```
public static void Count()
{
    int written = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    for (int i = written % 2; i <= written; i += 2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```